# Proof or counter-example that $(0,t_0)$ is a maximum of $f: [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ if $t_0$ is a maximum of $g(t) := f(0,t)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

Suppose $f: [0,1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function. Define $g(t) = f(0,t)$ and suppose that $g$ has a maximum in $t_0 \in (0,1)$, and suppose additionally that $D_1f(0,t_0) < 0$. I need to either prove, or give a counter-example to the fact that then $(0,t_0)$ is a local maximum of $f$.

Firstly it follows that $g'(t_0) = D_2f(0,t_0) = 0$. I have set up the Taylor expansion, write $\vec{a} = (0,t_0)$, then: 
$$
f(\vec{a} + \vec{h}) = f(\vec{a}) + D_1f(\vec{a})h_1 + D_2(\vec{a})h_2 + o(\|\vec{h}\|) = f(\vec{a}) + D_1f(\vec{a})h_1 + o(\|\vec{h}\|). 
$$
Now if $h_1 < 0$ it seems that $f(\vec{a} + \vec{h}) > f(\vec{a})$, or at least has the potential to be greater, so my guess is that it does not hold and we need to specify a counter-example. I have tried several but everything fails.

Comment: Is it assumed that $f$ has continuous second partials in some neighborhood of $(0,t_0)$?

Comment: It is not mentioned, so I think not necessarily.

Comment: I think maybe using negative $h_1$ will make the $a+h$ vector point the wrong way.

Comment: As in, out of the domain?

Comment: Yes, out of domain.

Comment: Yes you are right I think! I think that solves it! Because $a_1 =0$, so we cannot have a negative $h_1$, and then we must have $f(\vec{a} + \vec{h}) < f(\vec{a}) + o(\|\vec{h}\|)$, and we can probably somehow bound the latter term so that it is still smaller in a certain neighborhood and thus a local minimum.

Comment: Sigurd-- I still think the example you have now accepted doesn't rule out that the point in question is a *local* maximum of $f.$

Comment: Indeed you are right. I think it's vague, in the problem it just says `maximum', from the lecture I took that that means local maximum so I put that in the problem description, but I'm not so sure. Anyway, I now worked out both solutions, a proof for local maximum and a counter-example for global maximum, that should do. Thanks for your help in solving this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's build $f$ such that $g(t) = t-t^2$ (which attains its maximum at $t_0 = \dfrac12$) but which increases with $x$.

For this purpose, let's try $f(x,y) = x + y - y^2$. When we fix a value for $x$, the graph is simply the same parabola but translated to the top by $x$ (see below the drawing in $\Bbb R^3$ of the surface $z = f(x,y)$).

[image]

In this case, $f(0,0.5) = g(0.5) = 0.25$ but $f(1,0.5) = 1.25$ so that $(0,0.5)$ isn't a point of maximum of $f$.

**Edit:** I did not see the condition $D_1f(0,t_0)<0$. Thus I propose a new counterexample $f(x,y) = x^2-\dfrac12 x+y-y^2$ (see the new picture below).

Here, the idea was to add a function of $x$ (that is, $x^2-x$ here) which begins by decreasing when $x$ increases from 0 (in particular, $D_1f(0,0.5) = -\dfrac 12<0$) and then has a sufficiently strong increase when $x$ approaches $1$ so that $f(1,0.5)>f(0,0.5)$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, nice counter-example. Just wondering: $(0,0.5)$ is also not a local minimum of the function $f$ anymore right?

Comment: Wait a minute, this example fails since $D_1f(x,y) = 1 > 0$, but it should be smaller than $0$.

Comment: IMO this should be redone to address OP requirement $D_1<0.$

Comment: You're right! See my edit above.

Comment: The point $(1,0.5)$ is a bit far from the point $(0,0.5)$ where the local maximum is presumably to be in this example. Here $f(0,0.5)=0,$ so to contradict local max one wants points very *close* to that at which $f<0.$

Comment: Yes but you can rescale. If you want to have a function $f^*$ such that $f^*(\varepsilon,0.5) = f(1,0.5)$ then it suffices to choose $f^*(x,y) := f(x/\varepsilon,y)$.

Comment: paf-- Rescaling still won't take care of getting rid of a *local* max of $f$ (one could just "zoom in" sufficiently.)

Comment: Indeed, both of you guys are right. Honestly, the question is vaguely phrased, since it just says `maximum'. It is unclear if they mean global or local maximum, I assumed local but I'm not sure. Anyway, I now worked out a solution for both: for a local maximum, you can prove that this is indeed the case by the argument of the Taylor expansion. For a global argument: the counter-example of paf right here disproves this. Thanks for your help in solving this problem!

Comment: @Sigurd Yes for the local version I've worked out a proof using the definition of differentiable (function near tangent plane, bound on error etc.) Probably equivalent to Taylor expansion...

Comment: Indeed! that sounds good, that should indeed be the same since I used the Taylor expansion of order only 2, so then it is the same as the definition of differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

This example is built around a standard example of a function for which both partials exist at a point, yet the function behaves badly near the point. That will be called $q(x,y),$ and is $(xy)/(x^2+y^2)$ except at the origin where it is defined as $0.$ One can then show both partials of $q$ are $0$ at the origin.

For ease of discussion we redefine the domain to be $[-1,1] \times [0,1]$ and will take $t_0=0$ noting that this is in the open interval $(-1,1).$

Now define $f(x,y)=q(x,y)-x-y^2.$ We have $D_1(0,0)=-1<0$ as required. Also $g(t)=f(0,t)=-t^2$ which has its maximum at $0 \in (-1,1)$ where it is $0.$

Now $f$ fails to have a local maximum at the origin, since (for $t \neq 0$) $f(t,t)=1/2-t-t^2,$ which tends to $+1/2$ as $t \to 0.$

**Edit:** This example is *not* differentiable at the origin (the interior point of the left side of the altered domain).

Comment: Thanks you for the elaborate example. I'm wondering if it is possible to have a same sort of example on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$? Could it be the case that one key ingredient in the example is the fact that we have negative values on our input interval?

Comment: We could define an example on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ by first mapping $[-1,1]$ to $[0,1]$ via $x \to (1/2)x+1/2.$ This maps $0$ to $1/2 \in (0,1).$

Comment: @Sigurd I just realized the function $q(x,y)$ above is not differentiable (in the 2 variable sense) at $(0,0)$ which means neither is the function $f(x,y)$ I end up defining. I may delete this answer, but will leave it for now. Maybe someone will show your result holds if indeed $f$ is assumed differentiable. You may want to remove the accept until later...

Comment: Ah yeah you are right :/ This question seems a lot nastier than it appears at first sight. Indeed I almost begin believing the statement actually is true, but then I don't know what's wrong with the argument from the Taylor series I set up in the question.